# NSCopying, copyWithZone and NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nscopying

Firstly I would like confirmation that I have understood NSCopying correctly ...

In order to use a simple NSObject subclass as a key in an NSDictionary I must have it implement the NSCopying protocol. In the copied instance's copyWithZone method I must alloc/init a new instance of my class, set its properties to be identical to the copied instance and return it.

Secondly, why does an NSDictionary use a copy of the instance added to it rather than the instance itself?

Comment: Keys in a dictionary are copied. The objects are retained. Usually, strings are used as keys, and since they do conform to NSCopying, there's no issues. If for some reason you wanted to use some other kind of object, you'd have to make certain it conformed to NSCopying as well.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you explain why keys are copied?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394083/cocoas-nsdictionary-why-are-keys-copied

Comment: See comments on accepted thread for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subclass does not need to implement `NSCopying` if it is the object, the key should usually be `NSString`s, which are copied.

Comment: Right: Only keys need to implement `NSCopying`.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. The object will be used as a key. I've amended the question to reflect this. So why does it need a copy of the object rather than the object itself?

Comment: Also, if you need to have custom behaviour on your keys / objects, have a look at [CFDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFDictionaryRef/Reference/reference.html) and [CFMutableDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableDictionaryRef/Reference/reference.html) which are toll-free bridged to `NSDictionary` and `NSMutableDictionary`

Comment: Thanks for the links. Missed that first one somehow. Just found this as well which explains how to correctly implement an object for use as a key (and so you can use it for comparison) http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=73

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to implement NSCopying protocol for every custom class if you want make them copyable
2. It must use a copy because if you will modify an object contained in the original dictionary it's copy won't be affected by the change